# How to get TFS project child folders using TFS SDK

Tags: java, tfs-sdk

I am trying to fetch the child folders name for a given TFS project. As  of now I am able to connect to TFS server and list all the projects. Could please help me on how to get the child folder names for each TFS project.

```
TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = connectToTFS();

    // Enumerate the Team Projects.
    for (Project project : tpc.getWorkItemClient().getProjects())
    {
        System.out.println(project.getName());


    }



public static TFSTeamProjectCollection connectToTFS() throws URIException, SQLException
{
    TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = null;
    Credentials credentials;


    credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("USERNAME","PASSWORD");

    tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URIUtils.newURI("COLLECTION_URL"), credentials);

    return tpc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetExtendedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff734673.aspx) of the Workspace class.

```
getExtendedItems
public ExtendedItem[][] getExtendedItems(ItemSpec[] itemSpecs,
                                         DeletedState deletedState,
                                         ItemType itemType,
                                         GetItemsOptions options)
```

You can use the [Git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) project as a reference for using the TFS-SDK in Java.

Comment: We do not want to bring the code. we just want to get the directory structure without bringing the code.

Comment: @Angel I haven't tried this, but I think this method doesn't actually download the code. [Get()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139264.aspx) does.